# Plotly for python, only first data point is being graphed

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I am new to plotly and working on a script to generate a graph based on some results pulled from a database. However when I send the data over to plotly, only the first data point for each of the three traces is being graphed. I've verified that the lists contain the right data, I've even simply pasted the lists in instead of dynamically creating the variables. Unfortunately each time only the first data point is being graphed. Does anyone know what I am missing here? I am also open to another library if needed.

Is it also possible to have the x axis show as a string?

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
# Custom database class, works fine.
from classes.database import DatabaseConnection

# Database Connections and instances
db_instance = DatabaseConnection()
db_conn = db_instance.conn
db_cur = db_instance.cur



def main():


    # Get a list of versions and their stats.
    db_cur.execute(
        """
        select row_to_json(x) from
        (SELECT
               versions.version_number,
               cast(AVG(results.average) as double precision) as average,
               cast(AVG(results.minimum) as double precision) as minimum,
               cast(AVG(results.maximum) as double precision) as maximum
                  FROM versions,results
                    WHERE
                      versions.version_number = results.version_number
                      GROUP BY
                        versions.version_number) x;
                """
    )

    versions = []
    average = []
    minimum = []
    maximum = []

    unclean = db_cur.fetchall()

    # Create lists for x and y coordinates.
    for row in unclean:
        versions.append(row[0]['version_number'])
        average.append(int(row[0]['average']))
        minimum.append(int(row[0]['minimum']))
        maximum.append(int(row[0]['maximum']))

    grph_average = go.Scatter(
        x=versions,
        y=average,
        name = 'Average',
        mode='lines',
    )

    grph_minimum = go.Scatter(
        x=versions,
        y=minimum,
        name = 'Minimum',
        mode='lines',
    )

    grph_maximum = go.Scatter(
        x=versions,
        y=maximum,
        name = 'Maximum',
        mode='lines',
    )


    data = go.Data([grph_average, grph_minimum, grph_maximum])
    # Edit the layout
    layout = dict(title = 'Responses',
              xaxis = dict(title = 'Versions'),
              yaxis = dict(title = 'Ms'),
              )

    fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
    py.plot(fig, filename='response-times', auto_open=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The data that query returns is as follows, if you want to plug in the values :

```
versions = ['6.1', '5.0', '5.2'] 
average = [11232, 29391, 10429] 
minimum = [3641, 7729, 3483] 
maximum = [57440, 62535, 45201]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was an issue with my x axis. By adding some text before the version number and specifically type casting to a string I was able to get the graphs to generate properly.

```
# Create lists for x and y coordinates.
for row in unclean:
    versions.append("Version: " + str(row[0]['version_number']))
    average.append(int(row[0]['average']))
    minimum.append(int(row[0]['minimum']))
    maximum.append(int(row[0]['maximum']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some `matplotlib` that might get you started on this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

versions = ['6.1', '5.0', '5.2'] 
average = [11232, 29391, 10429] 
minimum = [3641, 7729, 3483] 
maximum = [57440, 62535, 45201]

plt.plot(minimum)
plt.plot(average)
plt.plot(maximum)
plt.xticks(range(len(versions)), versions)
```